# App Engine Class With Children Of The Same Type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm trying to save a tree structure in app engine.  My class has a parent and a list of children of the same type.  Everything works until I add the children property.  There are no errors when I call pm.makePersistent(), but the object is not saved.  Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

This is my class.  I'm using App Engine version 1.2.2.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Composite {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    @Persistent
    private String name;
    @Persistent
    private Composite parent;
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Composite> children;
    public Composite(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setParent(Composite parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Composite getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public List<Composite> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void addChild(Composite child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any success? Or do you have transfered the parent relationship handling to the DAO?

Comment: I've run into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the issue tracker for GAE/J DataNucleus plugin. Issues like

[Issue 73](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=73&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary)

[Issue 125](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=125&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: That's bad. Being able to construct tree like data structures is pretty important :-(